# Revert Revision of an Excel File - Drive API

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I have an Excel file on my Drive (web version). That Excel has many versions. I require the file every so often to revert to a specific version without deleting the most recent version.

I have the following code:

```
function revertRevisionExcel() {
  var revisionId = "######"; // Revision ID to revert.
  var fileId = "#####"; // Set the file ID.

  var endpoint = "";
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  Logger.log(token);
  var res = Drive.Revisions.get(fileId, revisionId);

  endpoint =
    "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" +
    fileId +
    "/revisions/" +
    revisionId +
    "?pageToken=" +
    token;

  var mediaData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint).getBlob();
  Drive.Files.update({}, fileId, mediaData);
}
```

When I run it shows me the error 401 "Login Required". Could any one please guide me?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

About your question of `When I run it shows me the error 401 "Login Required". Could any one please guide me?`, when I saw your script, I think that the following modification is required.

- `token` and `res` are not used.
- I think that `var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` cannot be used for the query parameter of `?pageToken=" + token`.

  - I think that the reason of your issue of `Login Required` is due to this. In this case, please use the access token retrieved by `var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()` to the request header.
- In order to retrieve the blob from the specific revision, please use `alt=media` in the query parameter.

When above modification points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function revertRevisionExcel() {
  var revisionId = "######"; // Revision ID to revert.
  var fileId = "#####"; // Set the file ID.

  var endpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "/revisions/" + revisionId + "?alt=media";
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var mediaData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpoint, {headers: {authorization: "Bearer " + token}}).getBlob();
  Drive.Files.update({}, fileId, mediaData);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that you have already enabled Drive API at Advanced Google services and the values of `revisionId` and `fileId` are the valid values. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Revisions: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/get)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Thank you, indeed the problem was related to the access token and it was not including "alt" in order to get the Blob.